# Filtrate XMLList using ".." notation

Tags: apache-flex, filter, xmllist

There is something I couldn't solve: when I search a specific node in a XMLList containing several level of hierarchy, filter never search in the top parent node.

For example, if I have a tree like this:

```
<node id="a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO" parentId="">
    <node id="a0KQ0000002PT8iMAG" parentId="a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO" />
</node>
```

and if I made a reseach like this:

```
var aNode = ac_hierarchy.source..node.(@id == "a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO")[0];
```

I will get no results, "aNode" will be null :/

Any idee ?

[EDIT]
There is something else I can't understand (and I'm searching for 2 days :/):

I recursively add nodes to the ac_hierarchy using the method bellow:

```
private function add_item_to_hierarchy(node:Node_vo):XML {
    var firstNode:XML = ac_hierarchy.getItemAt(0) as XML;
    var parentNode:XML;     

    if (firstNode.@[Node_vo.att_id] == node.parentId)
        parentNode = firstNode;
    else
        parentNode = ac_hierarchy.source..node.(@[Node_vo.att_id] == node.parentId)[0];


    var test:XML = ac_hierarchy.source..node.(@[Node_vo.att_id] == node.parentId)[0];
    var test2:XML = ac_hierarchy.source..node.(@[Node_vo.att_id] == "a0KQ0000002PT8iMAG")[0];

    newXmlNode = node.toXML();

    // Add the current node to his parent node
    parentNode.appendChild(newXmlNode);
}
```

The first time I call the "add_item_to_hierarchy" with "node.parentId" parameter equals to "a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO" method, ac_hierarchy looks like:

```
<node id="a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO" parentId="" />
```

var test:XML is filled.

var test2:XML is not filled.

It correctly appendChild.

The second time, "node.parentId" parameters equals to "a0KQ0000002PT8iMAG" and ac_hierarchy looks like:

```
<node id="a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO" parentId="">
    <node id="a0KQ0000002PT8iMAG" parentId="a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO"/>
</node>
```

var test:XML is filled.

var test2:XML is filled.

It also correctly appendChild.

And the third time, "node.parentId" parameters again equals to "a0KQ0000002PT8iMAG" and ac_hierarchy looks like:

```
<node id="a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO" parentId="">
    <node id="a0KQ0000002PT8iMAG" parentId="a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO">
        <node id="a0KQ0000002PTL9MAO"/>
    </node>
</node>
```

var test:XML is NOT filled.

var test2:XML is filled.

But this time, var "test" is null (although "node.parentId" value is the same as previous loop and test2 is correctly fill) !!!

I will soon break my computer :/

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide the whole XML with assigning to `ac_hierarchy` variable. Because of now I can suggest you should use `var aNode:XMLList = ac_hierarchy..node.(@id == "a0KQ0000002PTN5MAO")[0];`.

Comment: @Constantiner: Here is the declaration of my `ac_hierarchy` variable: `[Bindable] public var ac_hierarchy:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();` Unfortunately, using your sample give me the error bellow:
`1119: Access of possibly undefined property node through a reference with static type mx.collections:XMLListCollection.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, xml selectors don't check root node, but there are workarounds:

- Get your parent node into proxy XMLList and search it:

  var list:XMLList = new XMLList();
  list[0] = <node id="1"/>;
  var results:XMLList = list.(@id == "1");
- or just check parent node separately and add to search results.

Comment: This probably works but my aim was to search through the entire hierarchy with only one operation. It seems there is no way :/